# How to access multiple return values from executeFunction?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I've seen a bunch of examples of obtaining a single primitive result from `simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction`.  I need to know how to access a set of results.  `execute` returns a `Map`.  You have to provide `SqlOutParameter` to `executeFunction` and tell it the type to return.  Well I mapped the return to `MyCustomClass.class` and it is returning null.  I know the function will return 3 `BIGINT` out param values.

```
public class MyDao {
    private final JdbcTemplate theTemplate;;

    //@Autowired ctor

    public long createCategory(final CategoryEntity category) {
        final SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = getJdbcCall();

        return mapResult(jdbcCall.executeFunction(MyResultEntity.class, fromEntity(category)));
    }

    private long mapResult(MyResultEntity result) {
        return result.getOut_id();//FAIL
    }

    private SqlParameterSource fromEntity(final MyEntity category) {
        Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();

        params.put("in_name", category.getName());
        params.put("in_description", category.getDescription());

        SqlParameterSource result = new MapSqlParameterSource(params);

        return result;
    }

    private SimpleJdbcCall getJdbcCall() {
        //I need the value returned by "out_id"
        SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(theTemplate)
                .withSchemaName("mySchema")
                .withFunctionName("my_function")
                .declareParameters(
                        new SqlOutParameter("out_id", Types.BIGINT),
                        new SqlOutParameter("out_2", Types.BIGINT),
                        new SqlOutParameter("out_3", Types.BIGINT)
                );

                return jdbcCall;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that you can also use `execute` to call a function.  Then  just use the `Map` to get at the results:

```
public long createCategory(final MyEntity category) {
    final SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = getJdbcCall();

    Map<String, Object> results = jdbcCall.execute(fromEntity(category));
    return (long) results.get("out_id");
}
```